# Why is my user-defined function not being read in my main function?

Tags: c++, return, user-defined-functions

Im having an issue with getting my user-defined function to read in my main function, any advice or tips on what can cause this?

i tried different parameters, moving the function from below the main to above and it still ignores the code all together

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Fahrenheit, Celsius ;  
char y, Y ;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own 
getch, system("pause") or input loop */

using namespace std;
  char Answer ; 

    int FtoCTemp (int argc, char** argv){
    
        cout << "What Fahrenheit  Value Do You Want in Celsius" << endl; 
    cin >> Fahrenheit  ;                                                    
    
    Celsius = (Fahrenheit -32);          //2 equations used to get correct ouput                    
    Celsius = (Celsius * 5/9);
    
    cout << Celsius << " Celsius" << endl;   // prints Celsius after equation
    cout << "Would you like to enter another Fahrenheit" << endl;
    cin >> Answer;   // Captures answer 
    }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    do{      
        
        int FtoCTemp (int argc, char** argv);
     
    cout << "Would you like to enter another Fahrenheit" << endl;
    cin >> Answer;   // Captures answer 
    
    } while (Answer == 'y' || Answer == 'Y');
    
    cout << "Thank you!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We can't see your code so we have no idea. Add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: `int FtoCTemp (int argc, char** argv);` doesn’t call the function. It’s just a (redundant) declaration of the function that the compiler has already seen. To call it you need something like `FtoCTemp(argc, argv);`.

Comment: Next problem: `5/9` is 0.

Comment: i know 5/9 is 0 however it works for the equation my teacher gave me

Comment: Voted to reopen. This is clearly reproducible, and it’s not caused by a typo. Mistakes that you and I wouldn’t make aren’t automatically typos.  There’s a misunderstanding here that warrants an answer.

Comment: `(Celcius * 5/9)` does not calculate `5/9` as zero, since it calculates `Celcius * 5` first, then divides the result of that expression by `9`.

Comment: @Peter — good catch: multiplication groups left to right. Nevertheless …

Comment: Hey everyone I got it all solved thank you for the support

Comment: Two small side notes, there is no need to pass arg_c and arg_v on to your FtoCTemp function. So just make it `int FtoCTemp(int temperature_in_fahrenheit)`. The other thing is unlearn to use `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you're redeclaring the function in the loop, instead of
`int FtoCTemp (int argc, char** argv);` , try just writing `FtoCTemp (argc, argv);`

Comment: You’re right about the fix. But that’s not a redefinition. It’s a declaration. A declaration says “there’s something somewhere that looks like this”. A definition says “here it is”. In the code in the question the definition of that function comes before `main`. +1.

Comment: whoops, my bad, thanks for the correction, I mistook the terminology, it's fixed now

Comment: It’s a common mistake, but the difference is important.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is just as pointed out in the previous answer. There are also a few other problems, including double asking "...enter another..." and return value of FtoCTemp(). I put a proper version below with some explaination.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Variables declared outside all function bodies are global variables, which can be accessed by any function. For code clarity, try not to use them many.

//int Fahrenheit, Celsius ; // Since these variables are only used in FtoCTemp(), so move them into FtoCTemp() body.
//char y, Y ; // These variables are not used.

//using namespace std; // Duplicated.
//char Answer ; // Since this variable is only used in main(), so move it into main() body.

// Change return type of this function from "int" to "void" since it has no return value.
void FtoCTemp (int argc, char** argv){
    int Fahrenheit, Celsius;

    cout << "What Fahrenheit  Value Do You Want in Celsius" << endl; 
    cin >> Fahrenheit  ;                                                    
    
    // These two line code can be combined into one.
    //Celsius = (Fahrenheit -32);
    //Celsius = (Celsius * 5/9);
    Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;

    cout << Celsius << " Celsius" << endl;

    // The asking "...enter another..." here is removed because it has been asked in main().
    //cout << "Would you like to enter another Fahrenheit" << endl;
    //cin >> Answer;   // Captures answer 

    return; // For better coding custom, always "return" at the last line.
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char Answer;

    do{      
        FtoCTemp (argc, argv);
     
        cout << "Would you like to enter another Fahrenheit" << endl;
        cin >> Answer;   // Captures answer 
    
    } while (Answer == 'y' || Answer == 'Y');
    
    cout << "Thank you!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid the `std` namespace, don't return in void functions unless necessary (as in early return), and don't start your variables with an uppercase letter, you could use constants for `y` and `5/9`, you could use `tolower()` for answer. Besides that good answer

Comment: I disagree with `return; // For better coding custom, always "return" at the last line.`. It's just noise.

Comment: Please consider the original code is not much advanced. :)